# Surprisingly smart python import behaviour : what's happening under the hood?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Python imports are [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time), but I thought I finally understood them until I stumbled upon this behaviour (in 3.9.1). What is happening here?

Take this package structure:

```
countries/
├── __init__.py  # from . import greece
├── greece.py
└── spain.py
```

If I do `import countries`, the namespace `dir(countries)` only contains `greece`, as expected.

But if instead I start my session with:

```
from countries import spain
import countries
```

The namespace `dir(countries)` contains both `greece` and `spain` !

I know that `__init__.py` is run under the hood when I do the first import. What I don't understand is how python remembers to include both `greece` and `spain` in the `countries` namespace. Is it keeping the `countries` namespace saved somewhere under the hood after running `from countries import spain`, and then running `import countries` just adds it to the local namespace?

Comment: you can always print `sys.path` to have a look at the imports

Comment: If you have some time to burn, this talk by David Beazley is one of my favorite looks at python packages. http://www.dabeaz.com/modulepackage/

Comment: It's really interesting, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. When importing a module python keeps it in a list of imported modules. When you `from countries import spain` and then import the root, python knows that `spain` is a submodule of the parent `countries`. so when you `import countries` it just adds the submodules that you don't have to the parent.

see here for the actual logic: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f32c7950e0077b6d9a8e217c2796fc582f18ca08/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1007